# AS3 - declare variable with name of function parameter

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, function, variables

I have a function in my flash AS3 file. I'd like to pass a parameter when calling this function and have that parameter become the name of a new FLV playback component I'm declaring;

```
function newVideo(myVideoName){
var [myVideoName]:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
}
```

--
edit - I now have the following code. How would I add the FLV playback component to the stage?

```
> function newVideo(myVideoName:String):FLVPlayback {
>    
>     var flvP:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
>     flvP.name = myVideoName;
      flvP.source = "argentinaTrailer.f4v"; 
>     return flvP;
   }
> 
>  var myPlayer:FLVPlayback = newVideo('player1');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here is not allowed.  The notation for creating and accessing objects using a string reference (`this['someObject']`) does not permit you to cast a type.  Furthermore, objects created in this fashion cannot then be directly accessed using that name without using the identifier notation:

```
this['foo']:Object = {}; // fails, 1078: Label must be a simple identifier.
this['foo']        = {}; // works
```

and

```
this['foo'] = {};
trace(this.foo);    // fails, 1120: Access of undefined property foo.
trace(this['foo']); // works, [object Object]
```

So, to make your function work it should be written:

```
function newVideo(myVideoName:String):void
{
    this[myVideoName] = new FLVPlayback();
}
```

but you will only then be able to access the player by using that same string reference, like this:

```
this[myVideoName].play();
```

Furthermore, none of the above is giving the instance of the FLVPlayback component a name.  What it is doing is defining the name of a reference to your FLVPlayback.  If you are intending to create an FLVPlayback that has an instance name of `myVideoName` then you should create a function that looks like this:

```
function newVideo(myVideoName:String):FLVPlayback
{
    var flvP:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
    flvP.name = myVideoName;
    return flvP;
}
```

What this does is creates a new instance of the FLVPlayback component, assigns it an instance name, and returns a reference to it.  You would use it like this:

```
var myPlayer:FLVPlayback = newVideo('player1');
addChild(myPlayer);
```

Comment: Thanks for that - it makes sense. However, I've previously been adding the FLVPlayback component to the stage using addChild. Could you explain how I would incorporate this into your function as it doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: I'll be happy to edit the answer with more info, but could you explain what you mean by 'not working'?

Comment: Hi Shane, I've edited my question with the code I now have thanks to your answer. I've set a source parameter - how would I now add the FLV playback component to the stage?

Comment: @user469453 - I've updated my answer, if that's not working for you I'll need some details of the type of error you're getting.

Comment: Hi Shane - thats really helped. Thanks a lot - this will save me a lot of time and lines of code :)